# Method name is not defined when calling it in class definition

Tags: python, class

I'm currently coding a caesar cipher encoding and decoding app for school, where you should enter a shift letter (only lowercase) and you should be able to encode or decode the message.

The current issue is

> NameError: name 'shift_amount' is not defined

In the encoded message section there's what I needed to do in the code below it, but I don't think that it was completed correctly. There will be issues in the code at the bottom for how to print it out, but the main issue that I would like to figure out how to fix is the code inside of the `def encoded`/`def decoded`.

This is the code:

```
lower_case=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
upper_case=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']


class CaesarCipher:
    
    def encode(text, shift_key):
        print(f"encode message {text} with {shift_key}")
        encoded_msg=text
        num=shift_amount(shift_key)
        #find the test letter

        #print the index for this number

        #add the num to that index

        #print the new letter
        for chr in text:
            if chr.islower():
                shifted_chr = CaesarCipher.lower_case[(CaesarCipher.lower_case.index(chr) + shift) % 26]
                encoded_msg += shifted_chr
            else:
                encoded_msg += chr
        return encoded_msg
    
    def decode(text, shift_key):
        print(f"decode message {text} with {shift_key}")
        decoded_msg=text
        num=shift_amount(shift_key)
        for chr in text:
            if chr.islower():
                shifted_chr = CaesarCipher.lower_case[(CaesarCipher.lower_case.index(chr) - shift) % 26]
                decoded_msg += shifted_chr
            else:
                decoded_msg += chr
        return decoded_msg 

    def shift_amount(shift_key):
        #do something (how many shifts?)
        #a=0,b=1,z=25
        matching_index = -1
        count=0
        if shift_key in lower_case:
            print("it's valid")
            while count < len(lower_case):
                if shift_key == lower_case [count]:
                    matching_index = count
                    print(f"found matching index: {lower_case[count]}")
                    return matching_index
                else:
                    print("it's failed")
                count +=1
                
        else:
            print("Invalid")

    encode("hello","b")
    decode("hello","b")

    shift_key=input("choose a shift amount ")
    num=shift_amount(shift_key)
    print(f"Number is {str(num)}")
```

Comment: PSA: You don't need to go through the trouble of splitting up characters like that. A simple string will work, or even a `range`. Remember `"abc"[n]` is a thing.

Comment: Your class makes no sense. Why did you even define `class CaesarCipher:`? It has no state, it has no inheritance, and you neglected to make any instances of it, have any of the methods take `self`, etc. Just get rid of `class CaesarCipher:` and all instances of `CaesarCipher.`, and dedent all of its contents, and your initial problem will disappear (and probably others you haven't run into yet).

Comment: @tadman I've deleted all the code except for     def encode(text, shift_key):
        print(f"encode message {text} with {shift_key}")
        encoded_msg=text
        #find the test letter

        #print the index for this number

        #add the num to that index

        #print the new lettere
        return encoded_msg   -> how do I implement range into this? my teacher told me a way that isn't working and hasn't taught us range

Comment: @Flo: tadman's suggestion is about code simplification. It's not something that is strictly *wrong* with your code, you just went about things in an inefficient way. Changing what he's talking about won't fix your problem.